# Random String generator in C

Tags: c, strings, random, generator

I created this small function just to practice C code.  It's a simple random string generator.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char *randstring(int length) {    
    static int mySeed = 25011984;
    char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    size_t stringLen = strlen(string);        
    char *randomString = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL) * length + ++mySeed);

    if (length < 1) {
        length = 1;
    }

    randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));

    if (randomString) {
        short key = 0;

        for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
            key = rand() % stringLen;          
            randomString[n] = string[key];
        }

        randomString[length] = '\0';

        return randomString;        
    }
    else {
        printf("No memory");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The code seems to work ok. 
Any ideas, improvements or bugs?

I added the `mySeed` var so that if I call it twice with the same length it doesn't give me the same exact string.

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code to this:

```
char *randstring(size_t length) {

    static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";        
    char *randomString = NULL;

    if (length) {
        randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));

        if (randomString) {            
            for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
                int key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset) -1);
                randomString[n] = charset[key];
            }

            randomString[length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return randomString;
}
```

I know that in the `sizeof(charset)` you don't have to use the `()`. You only need them when using sizeof with types, but it's just out of habit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your function is nice but has a few issues, the main one being that it
  should not call `srand`.  `srand` should be called elsewhere (eg in `main`)
  just once.  This seeds the random number generator, which need only be done
  once.

A minor issue is that `string` is badly named - `charset` might be better.
  It should be `const` and you then need not call `strlen` to find its length
  `sizeof charset -1` is enough.  For me, randomString is an unnecessarily
  long name.

On failing to allocate memory for the string, I would prefer to see a NULL
  return than an `exit`.  If you want an error message, use `perror`, but
  perhaps in the caller, not here.  I would be inclined to avoid the
  possibility of such an error but passing in the buffer and its length
  instead of allocating.

Some minor points: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition and using `short` for
  `key` is pointless - just use `int`.  Also `key` should be defined where it
  is used and I would leave a space after the ; in the for loop definition.

Note also that using `rand() % n` assumes that the modulo division
  is random - that is not what `rand` promises.

Here is how I might do it:

```
static char *rand_string(char *str, size_t size)
{
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJK...";
    if (size) {
        --size;
        for (size_t n = 0; n < size; n++) {
            int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof charset - 1);
            str[n] = charset[key];
        }
        str[size] = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}
```

**Edit** July 31 23:07UTC

Why would I write the function to take a buffer instead of allocating the
string inside the function?

Returning dynamically allocated strings works fine.  And if the memory is
later freed there is no problem.  But writing this sort of function is a great
way to leak memory, for example if the caller doesn't know the memory must be
freed or forgets to free memory, or even if he frees it in the main path but
forgets to free it in other paths etc.

Memory leaks in a desktop applications might not be fatal, but leaks in an
embedded system will lead eventually to failure.  This can be serious,
depending upon the system involved.  In many embedded systems, dynamic
allocation is often not allowed or is at least best avoided.

Although it certainly is common **not** to know the size of strings or buffers
at compile time, the opposite is also often true.  It is often possible to
write code with fixed buffer sizes.  I always prefer this option if possible
so I would be reluctant to use your allocating function.  Perhaps it is better
to add a wrapper to a non-allocating function for those cases where you really
must allocate dynamically (for example when the random string has to outlive the calling context):

```
char* rand_string_alloc(size_t size)
{
     char *s = malloc(size + 1);
     if (s) {
         rand_string(s, size);
     }
     return s;
}
```

Comment: note that you don't need to return any result because the str parameter is mutable

Comment: That is true but many standard library functions do this too. It can make life easier, eg in `printf("%s\n", rand_string(buf, sizeof buf));`

Comment: your right, if you speak of easy life you grab c++,java,go,python,haskell,ruby or d unless your really need the last 100%-20% performance or your forced to use c

Comment: The questioner is asking specifically about C, not C++, not Java, not go, python etc.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @WilliamMorris Could you provide some more insight on why you pass the buffer and not just create the buffer in the string with malloc and return it? Is it because this way it would be easier to free the memory? Is it not possible to free the returned pointer? Thanks.

Comment: Added some notes to my answer on allocating vs passing a buffer

Comment: Just to point out (I'm sure you know, but you didn't make it explicit), `sizeof charset` works for `const char charset[]` but is wrong for `const char *charset`.

Comment: On the note of using `int`, everywhere you use `int` you include the possibility that a compiler for a given architecture might introduce sign handling overhead... probably best to use `size_t` for things like sizes or indexes of arrays. It'll all end up in a register, at the end of the day anyway, but this way it might end up in a *better* register in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to also give a small input. I had to implement a very similar function for a project of mine. I can't disclose the algorithm, however. But let me try to give you a couple small hints as to how you could further improve yours. I'm foremost concerned with stability and performance (low latency and high throughput) of code.

Let's start with this (profiled for a **1024-byte long string for 10,000 iterations** with gprof):

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
 67.16      0.02     0.02    10000     2.01     2.01  randstring
 33.58      0.03     0.01    10000     1.01     1.01  mkrndstr
  0.00      0.03     0.00    10000     1.01     1.01  mkrndstrperf
```

The difference is here really thin as on a few repetitions gprof gives random data, so let's take callgrind instead.

The total cost is then more precisely calculated in function calls:

```
 7,986,402,268  ???:randstring [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 6,655,222,307  ???:mkrndstr [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 6,653,436,779  ???:mkrndstr_ipa [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 6,653,436,778  ???:mkrndstr_ipd [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
```

For a **10-byte long string and 10,000 calls**, the relative difference is even bigger:

```
 9,968,042  ???:randstring [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 8,646,775  ???:mkrndstr [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 6,716,774  ???:mkrndstr_ipa [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
 6,716,774  ???:mkrndstr_ipd [~perf/t/mkrndstr-notmine]
```

Here, `mkrndstr_ip{a,d}` means: in-place for automatically stored and dynamically stored data (different calls, identical functions), respectively.

---

Some key take-aways beforehand:

1. down-casting

   ```
   size_t l = (sizeof(charset) -1);   // uncast
   ```

   versus

   ```
   int l = (int)(sizeof(charset) -1); // cast to int as suggested in William Morris' reply
   ```

   makes on that scale a big difference--you avoid passing around loads of superfluous bytes.
2. The static set of chars is a good idea, saves many cycles and calls, I'd prefix it with a const qualifier.
3. It's a bad idea to do per-cycle/per-iteration instantiations and identical calculations for the same reasons as in 2 above, make the value, loosely speaking, sticky as Quonux demonstrates it.
4. Considering randomness. I guess you know libc's `rand()` is an implementation of a PRNG. It's useless for anything serious. If your code gets executed too quickly, i.e., when there's too little interval between any two successive calls to `rand()`, you'll get the same character from the set. So make sure to pause for a couple CPU cycles. You could also simply read chunks from `/dev/urandom` (with the `u` prefix, otherwise my "simply" wouldn't hold) or similar on a UNIX derivative. Don't know how to access the random device on Windows.
5. `strlen` is indeed slower than `sizeof` for clear reasons (expects complex strings), see the implementation in glibc sources, for example, in `string/strlen.c`.
6. The rest is in the comments.

---

Let's get to the code:

1. **Yours, final**:

   ```
   char *randstring(size_t length) { // length should be qualified as const if you follow a rigorous standard

   static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";    
   char *randomString;   // initializing to NULL isn't necessary as malloc() returns NULL if it couldn't allocate memory as requested

   if (length) {
       randomString = malloc(length +1); // I removed your `sizeof(char) * (length +1)` as sizeof(char) == 1, cf. C99

       if (randomString) {        
           for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {        
               int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof(charset) -1);
               randomString[n] = charset[key];
           }

           randomString[length] = '\0';
       }
   }

   return randomString;
   }
   ```
2. **Mine** (only slight optimizations):

   ```
   char *mkrndstr(size_t length) { // const size_t length, supra

   static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!"; // could be const
   char *randomString;

   if (length) {
       randomString = malloc(length +1); // sizeof(char) == 1, cf. C99

       if (randomString) {
           int l = (int) (sizeof(charset) -1); // (static/global, could be const or #define SZ, would be even better)
           int key;  // one-time instantiation (static/global would be even better)
           for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {        
               key = rand() % l;   // no instantiation, just assignment, no overhead from sizeof
               randomString[n] = charset[key];
           }

           randomString[length] = '\0';
       }
   }

   return randomString;
   }
   ```
3. Now considering your question regarding **dynamic versus automatic data storage**:

   ```
   void mkrndstr_ipa(size_t length, char *randomString) { // const size_t length, supra

   static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";

   if (length) {
       if (randomString) {
           int l = (int) (sizeof(charset) -1);
           for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {
               int key = rand() % l;          // per-iteration instantiation
               randomString[n] = charset[key];
           }

           randomString[length] = '\0';
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   There's also an identical function with the modified name as stated way above. Both are called like this:

   ```
   char *c = malloc(SZ_STR +1);    // dynamic, in C on the heap
   char d[SZ_STR +1];              // "automatic," in C on the stack
   mkrndstr_ipd(SZ_STR, c);
   mkrndstr_ipa(SZ_STR, d);
   ```

   1. [Here's a short note on memory allocation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500497/2579089)
   2. [Here's a more visual note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/662454/2579089)

---

Now the more interesting part:

```
    .globl  randstring
    .type   randstring, @function
randstring:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    call    mcount
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -40(%rbp)
    je  .L2
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    malloc
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    je  .L2
    movl    $0, -28(%rbp)
    jmp .L3
.L4:
    call    rand
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    $1991868891, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    imull   %edx
    sarl    $5, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    movl    %edx, %ebx
    subl    %eax, %ebx
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)
    movl    -32(%rbp), %eax
    imull   $69, %eax, %eax
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    movl    -32(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  charset.1808(%rax), %eax
    movb    %al, (%rdx)
    addl    $1, -28(%rbp)
.L3:
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    cmpq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    jb  .L4
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movb    $0, (%rax)
.L2:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   randstring, .-randstring
```

compared with:

```
    .globl  mkrndstr
    .type   mkrndstr, @function
mkrndstr:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $48, %rsp
    call    mcount
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -40(%rbp)
    je  .L7
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    malloc
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    je  .L7
    movl    $69, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    jmp .L8
.L9:
    call    rand
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl   -16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  charset.1818(%rax), %eax
    movb    %al, (%rdx)
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
.L8:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    cmpq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    jb  .L9
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movb    $0, (%rax)
.L7:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   mkrndstr, .-mkrndstr
```

I believe an interpretation is not necessary here, the disassembly is then only for visualisation. Compare the different number of instructions.

What I wanted to show is that just a couple of tiny nip'n'tucks does wonders. We sure could go memmove the string into an external buffer at a fixed address or do n-byte-wise assignments. We could also put the set in a macro or use even more static allocation. But let's not exaggerate and go write this outright in ASM, and when we'd be done with it, do the same in pure machine code.

I hope this helps and if it's not a real-time system, then don't do much hassle with the optimizations, stability and reliability (like `rand()`) should go first. If you optimize this and that out, something else somewhere else could break. There are a few open-source projects online that show how to optimize excessively but at the cost of an unmaintanable code for newcomers to their teams and sheer complexity for the more accustomed developers.

Last thing I'd like to point you at is that

> error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Comment: I would not expect either putting the size into a variable or defining the `key` variable outside the loop to make any difference.  The compiler can optimise this away. With `gcc` using `-O2` the two functions (randstring, mkrndstr)  give identical assembler.  The same is true of `clang`.  How are you compiling (which compiler/options)?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for such an in-depth analysis of my code.

Comment: @William: I generally test performance without any compiler optimizations. `-O2`, in my opinion, does not always produce stable binaries, it's more about compatibility of your code and the optimizations specified to the compiler. That was an assembly by `gcc`. Besides, not always do I run my code on x86 machines, so it may differ again. When I do fine-tuning, I manually pick optimizations instead of the predefined bundles. I prefer to get my code as I want it instead of trusting some compiler that it would improve it. By the way, this also applies to interpreted languages like Perl and Python.

Comment: @Antonio: hope you'll find even more ways to improve your code, there really is always room for improvement, for everyone, at any step in your program. You never stop learning -- that's what I love most about programming.

Comment: The thing is, code that looks shorter in assembly is not necessarily quicker.  Your optimisation of moving the size of the character set to a variable causes the compiler (gcc on IA32) to emit an `idiv` instruction instead of using its most efficient method of dividing by `sizeof charset - 1` (69).  Testing just this division with gcc on OS-X and Linux, your code, which uses `idiv`, is shorter but takes twice as long.  With -O2 and with or without a separate variable for the size, the code is shorter still and takes a quarter of the time of the unoptimised `idiv` code.

Comment: @AntinioCS, note that worrying about performance of any particular function is best avoided unless you find you have performance problems. In that case you should find the performance bottlenecks and optimise just those.

Answer (score 3):

the code doesn't look that wrong, but

- the caller should allways check for errors
- `if (length < 1)` test unnecessary
- `srand(time(NULL)` should be done outside
- error catching (`malloc`) should open no new block
- `short` isn't really at the high of the time, use it only for serilizing/deserilizing raw binary files/network data
- use `unsigned` if it makes sense, **the counter can't be negative** and this is not lala-java-land (besides it can be a bit faster but most times it doesn't matter) (side note, yes i am damaged from looking at the assembler output of the compilers)
- you don't need to recalculate the `string` length everytime, with *C++0x* you can maybe let it calculate from the compiler on compiletime

  ```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <time.h>

  char *randstring(int length) {    
      char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
      size_t stringLen = 26*2+10+7;        
      char *randomString;

      randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));

      if (!randomString) {
          return (char*)0;
      }

      unsigned int key = 0;

      for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
          key = rand() % stringLen;          
          randomString[n] = string[key];
      }

      randomString[length] = '\0';

      return randomString;
  }
  ```

Comment: The `unsigned` (`size_t` to be more specific) applies to the `size` parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem with this code: it doesn't generate a random string each time the program is run. The code is missing `srand(time(0));`. The `srand()` function sets the starting point for producing a series of pseudo-random integers. If `srand()` is not called, the `rand()` seed is set as if `srand(1)` were called at program start. Any other value for seed sets the generator to a different starting point.

For more details, read [**rand() and srand() in C/C++**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)

Comment: [As William Morris points out](/a/29200) (first paragraph), it does call `srand()` - unfortunately it does so on each call of the function, rather than once in the `main()`.

Comment: Yeah William pointed that out, and it doesn't need to call `srand()` every function call once in `main()` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. It's ok to use a charset but I would recommend using ASCII values to save some memory (not that it matters too much). You can check out ASCII values here, for example, https://www.asciitable.com/ and then you set the interval of numbers you want. In the example below I will use 32-126. Also, as it was already said, you should call `srand` on `main` or something, since it should be called only once.

What I mean is something like:

```
#define ASCII_START 32
#define ASCII_END 126

char* generateRandomString(int size) {
    int i;
    char *res = malloc(size + 1);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res[i] = (char) (rand()%(ASCII_END-ASCII_START))+ASCII_START;
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}
//srand is not visible, as I said it could be on main.
```